# How to find favicon when it isn't in the standard location

Tags: javascript, favicon

This is a section of my page of links:
[image: Names of sites, each preceded by its favicon]

The individual icons are inserted with this code:

```
<script> "use strict"
    let anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    for (let a=0; a<anchors.length; ++a) {
        if ("undefined" !== typeof anchors[a].href) {
            let d = document.createElement("div")
            let i = document.createElement("img")
            i.setAttribute("alt", "")
            i.setAttribute("class", "favicon")
            i.setAttribute("src", anchors[a].href.replace(/^(.*:\/\/[^\/]*).*/, "$1"+"/favicon.ico"))
            d.appendChild(i)
            d.setAttribute("class", "logo")
            anchors[a].insertBefore(d, anchors[a].childNodes[0])
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
        for (let i=0; i<anchors.length; ++i)
            if ( (typeof images[i].naturalWidth !== "undefined") && (images[i].naturalWidth === 0) )
                images[i].src = ".Images/Oops.svg"
    }
</script>
```

The problem is, a few sites, such as *Duolingo* and *Google/Webmaster*, don't have a `favicon.ico` in their root directory.

Short of manually fetching and storing copies of them on my own site, is there any way to find the appropriate `<img src="…" />` URLs for sites that lack a `favicon.ico` in the standard location?

Comment: Sadly I think that your going to need to have some specific path to look in - you could use a "regex" to crawl a site looking for files with the fav-icon but without knowledge of where they are specifically you may not find the file you need. Can you provide more info? are you trying to find the fav icon in a data-base where you know it will be there or from external sites?

Comment: @Wally, I was simply using the standard location to find the file in a trivial way.  Building my own database is far more work than it's worth (to me at least).

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from

```
<link rel="icon"              href="path_to_favicon">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon"  href="path_to_favicon">
```

Javascript:

```
function get_favicon() {
    let links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
    for(let a=0; a < links.length; a++) {
        let link = links[a];
        let attr = link.getAttribute("rel");
        if(attr == "icon" || attr == "apple-touch-icon" || attr == "mask-icon" || attr == "shortcut icon") {
            return link.getAttribute("href");
        }
    }
}
```

This is not [exhaustive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon), but you can setup this extralayer to deduce favicon location.

Comment: This assumes that my page can read the source of the other site's page.  As far as I know, that isn't possible.

Comment: Effectively this cannot be done by the client but if you really need theses icons, you can establish a database of favicons (by running a crawling daemon on your server). Then you display favicon from your database. A little heavy method, I assume :/